# Edit background color on a button (active link)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to edit the color on this button when its active http://prntscr.com/f35k6r to a more light grey color instead of #000, but i cant figure that out. it has same settings as the other buttons? URL: http://welloteket.se/varumarken/

Can someone help me out? Whats wrong?

Comment: could you please provide us for some code? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you inspect the element you can see in the Chrome Dev Tools (F12) under 'Styles' the css you need which is highlighted.

`.ubermenu-skin-grey-white .ubermenu-item-level-0.ubermenu-current-menu-item > .ubermenu-target{background:#cccccc;}`

[image]

Comment: Yes exactly, but why is is #000 on this link?

Comment: I took alook at the css files and this is setup in the Theme options of your theme.